# Syntax question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are these variables?

```
Class User
  TOTO = 1
  TITI = 2
end

User::TOTO # 1
User::TITI # 2
```

any links to the doc?
Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TOTO` and `TITI` are defined as constants with values 1 and 2 respectively within the User class.

You can access these constants from within the the user class itself by just referring them as `TOTO` and `TITI`

But if you want to access these constants from outside the user class then you have to use the class name as well which is what you are doing I guess, i.e. `User::TOTO` and `User:TITI`

Here is [little tutorial on the constants](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html).

Answer (score 2):

`Class` should be lowercase, for one.

```
class User
  TOTO = 1
  TITI = 2
end

User::TOTO # 1
User::TITI # 2
```

`User`, `TOTO` and `TITI` are all constants, with `User` referencing a class, and `TOTO` and `TITI` both being stored inside that class's namespace and both referencing integers.

In ruby, you have several types of variable, all identified by theit starting character.

- local variables begin with a lowercase letter, and are only accessible within the scope that they are first defined in.
- constants begin with an uppercase letter, and are accessible within and through the namespace (class or module) that they are defined in.
- instance variables begin with a single `@` sign, and are accessible whenever `self` evaluates to the instance that eh instance variable was defined in (normally within instance methods)
- class variables begin with a `@@` sign, and are acessible whenever inside the class that first defined them, or any of its subclasses, or any of their instances.